# Not able to register Lit component in Vue 2 class components

Tags: vuejs2, web-component, lit, lit-html, vue-class-components

I have created a Lit component in typescript. It is being exported as a named export. I am not able to register it in Vue 2 class component. Here are the issues I am facing:

Issue 1:

```
import { MyElement } from 'vite-project';
@Component({
        components: {
            MyElement
        },
```

This gives below runtime error

```
vue.runtime.esm.js:4020 TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
    at _classCallCheck (classCallCheck.js:3:1)
    at M (my-element.ts:18:1)
    at resolveAsyncComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js:2722:1)
    at createComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js:2142:1)
    at _createElement (vue.runtime.esm.js:2319:1)
    at createElement$1 (vue.runtime.esm.js:2269:1)
    at vm._c (vue.runtime.esm.js:2561:1)
    at Proxy.render (Console.vue:23:1)
    at Vue._render (vue.runtime.esm.js:2610:1)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js:3045:1)
```

Issue 2:

The component gets registered and works well if I import it as default export like

```
import MyElement from 'vite-project';
```

But this gives compile time warning that

```
"export 'default' (imported as 'MyElement') was not found in 'vite-project/dist/my-element'
```

Above warning is correct since I am not exporting MyElement as a default export.

I also tried exporting MyElement as default but again it gives the same runtime error.

Please help.

Web Component Code:

```
import { html, css, LitElement } from 'lit';
import { customElement, property } from 'lit/decorators.js';

@customElement('my-element')
export default class MyElement extends LitElement {
  static styles = css`
    :host {
      display: block;
      padding: 25px;
    }
  `;

  @property({ type: String }) header = 'Hey there';

  @property({ type: Number }) counter = 5;

  __increment() {
    this.counter += 1;
  }

  handle(e: any) {
    console.log(e)
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <h2>${this.header} Nr. ${this.counter}!</h2>
      <button @click=${this.__increment}>increment</button>
    `;
  }
}
```

I should be able to register the component in Vue 2 class component

Comment: Can you share your webcomponent code also

Comment: I have edited and added the web component code

Comment: you could import wc in vue using import {default as MyElement } from './path'

Comment: Doesn't work. It still give this compile time warning
""export 'default' (imported as 'MyElement') was not found in './path'"

Comment: I am not familiar with the Vue 2 component registration object that you have shown in your example, but it most likely expects another Vue component, instead of a native element. Your Lit example already registers your component on the browser (via the `@customElement('my-element')` decorator), therefore you can side effect import your component with `import "vite-project"`, and it should be defined in the browser and work in the Vue template. Vue config changes may also be required so Vue lets the browser handle the web components: https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html